# How to work on "Do" loop?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, infinite-loop

let's say

```
parameter={a->2, b->3
c->Range[1,10,0.5],
d->Range[1,10,0.5]}
 

Do[ eqa[parameter_]:=Module[{a,b,c,d},

    cd=c[i]*d[j]/.parameter]]

    eqa[parameter]
```

I expect the result should be

[image]

Refer to c->Range[1,10,0.5] is {a,b,c,d}
d->Range[1,10,0.5] is {A,B,C,D}

Finally, I'd like to see the results in table form, as shown in the image above.

Edited2:

The way you showed is the result that I expect. Unfortunately, I can't implement it with my code. I literally get it all but the final results are wrong.

```
parameters={a->2, b->3
width->Range[1,10,0.5],
lenght->Range[1,10,0.5]}

eqa[parameters_]:=Module[{a,b,lenght,width}

aw = Flatten[Transpose[{width} /. parameters]];
bl = Flatten[Transpose[{lenght} /. parameters]];
area = Outer[Times, aw, bl];
cir = Outer[Plus, 2*aw, 2*bl];
uef=(area/cir)*a/.parameters;]

eqa[parameters]
```

the results of area and cir are perfect but when it operates with uef, it doesn't get the right answer. I am confused.

Comment: Are you missing some syntax here? `Do` takes two arguments, the expression to evaluate each iteration and the iterator. You also seem to be making a pattern-matching definition inside a `Do` loop, which would just overwrite the definition each time...do the examples in the help docs for `Do` make sense?

Comment: Move `Module` outside the `Do` loop. Makes no sense to redefine the function every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

parameter = {a -> 2, b -> 3 , c -> Range[1, 10, 0.5], 
   d -> Range[1, 10, 0.5]};

Flatten[Transpose[{c, d} /. parameter] /. {x_, y_} :> {x*y}]

(* {1., 2.25, 4., 6.25, 9., 12.25, 16., 20.25, 25., 30.25, 36., 42.25, 
    49., 56.25, 64., 72.25, 81., 90.25, 100.} *)

c*d /. parameter

(* {1., 2.25, 4., 6.25, 9., 12.25, 16., 20.25, 25., 30.25, 36., 42.25, 
    49., 56.25, 64., 72.25, 81., 90.25, 100.} *)

% === %%

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** For revised question

```
Clear["Global`*"]

v1 = {A, B, C, D};

v2 = {a, b, c, d};

TableForm[tab1 = Outer[HoldForm[Times[#2, #1]] &, v1, v2],
 TableHeadings -> {v1, v2}]
```

[image]

```
parameter = {a -> 2, b -> 3, c -> Range[1, 10, 1/2], 
   d -> Range[1, 10, 1/2]};

With[{v1 = c /. parameter, v2 = d /. parameter},
 TableForm[tab2 = Outer[Times, v1, v2],
   TableHeadings -> {v1, v2}] /. r_Rational :> N[r]]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** For your latest change,

In the list of rules you keep leaving out a comma (after `b -> 3`).

I changed to the standard spelling of `length`.

```
parameters = {a -> 2, b -> 3, width -> Range[1, 10, 0.5], 
   length -> Range[1, 10, 0.5]};
```

If you make the variables local to the `Module`, the names in the `Module` are not the same as those in the `Global` namespace and the replacements won't work. Alternatively, move the definition of `parameters` into the `Module`.

The way that you did the replacements makes no sense.

You were missing a comma in the `Module` and you suppressed any output with the final semicolon.

```
eqa[parameters_] := Module[{}, 
  aw = width /. parameters;
  bl = length /. parameters;
  area = Outer[Times, aw, bl];
  cir = Outer[Plus, 2*aw, 2*bl];
  uef = (area/cir)*a /. parameters]

TableForm[tab = eqa[parameters],
 TableHeadings -> {aw, bl}]
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry I was wrong. I actually want to get c=[1,2,3,4] d=[1,2,3,4]
if c*d ,it should be 1*1, 1*2,1*3
2*1,*2*2, 2*3

Something like this like a matrix. I am sorry I was wrong about using transpose.

Comment: Edit your question to reflect what you actually want. Show the full result that you are expecting.

Comment: I already add more info. I hope it can clear thing up.

Comment: The results were perfect but the final results were wrong when it was implemented with other equations.

Comment: Hi, it works perfectly. It was my fault. I put the wrong variables. Everything works perfectly now. Thank you very much.